# Change tag 31 in Fix4.4

Tags: java, fix-protocol

I am using FIX protocol and I need tag 31 to be of string type.
Originally it is of type price which means a float or double.
I was just wondering if it will have issues(currently i don't see any issues)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using QuickFIX/J, you only tagged fix-protocol and java.

Since the data is transmitted over the wire as Strings anyway you won't have issues with your counterparty.

The only issue that might occur is that when receiving messages you need to make sure that your data dictionary and your code both process the field correctly. You cannot be sure that the received value in the field will be of type "price" anymore. Your counterparty could now send any String value in the field which could make your code fail.

But in general every value is converted to String internally anyway.